Tensorflow dataset: reading ragged tensor from parquet
Is it possible to read ragged tensors with tfio's from_parquet?  Without specifying a RaggedTensorSpec it returns them as one (joined) tensor, truncated after n rows.  Specifying a (possibly incorrect?) RaggedTensorSpec gives an InvalidArgumentError.
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_io as tfio

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]})
df.to_parquet('/tmp/df.pq')

## wrong layout without spec
ds = tfio.IODataset.from_parquet('/tmp/df.pq')
for x in ds.take(3):
    print(x)
# OrderedDict([(b'x.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>)])
# OrderedDict([(b'x.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>)])
# OrderedDict([(b'x.list.element', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>)])

## error with spec
ds = tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(
    '/tmp/df.pq',
    columns={'x': tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=[3, None], ragged_rank=1)})
# InvalidArgumentError: {{[...]}} slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds


Hi @raywib,you are facing an error while ragged tensors from parquet file. So when you are saving ragged data in parquet the column should be represented as list of lists . Make sure tensorFlow interprets the data correctly and Ensure that the Parquet file is correctly formatted.Check all the points and let me know if you are still need help,Thanks.
